# Chaining loc and update not working, why?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to update a column A in dataframe df using data from column B in dataframe df2 but only rows that have 0 in column C.

I am trying the following, but it does not change the values in df

```
df.loc[df["C"]==0,"A"].update(df2["B"])
```

how to correct this line?

Comment: `df.loc[...]` creates a *new pandas object* (a `pd.Series` here I think). Then you update that object, then never assign the result to anything, so it is immediately garbage collected

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga if this was the case why df.loc[...]= value works correctly?

Comment: @DominikLisiakiewicz because `df.loc[...] = ` calls a *mutator method*. So, it is important to understand that `x[item]` is different than `x[item] = whatever`. `x[...]` is equivalent to `x.__getitem__(item)`, whereas `x[item] = whatever` is equivalent to `x.__setitem__(item, whatever)`

Comment: of course, `df.loc[...]` could potentialyl do whatever it wants. Indeed, in pandas, it may generate a view, but in this case with a boolean index it will always generate an independent (non-view) object

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct answer, which apparently also alines both data by the index

```
df.loc[df["C"]==0,"A"]=df2.loc[:,"B"]
```

But why my previous line did not work?

Answer (score 0):

```py
df['A'].update( df['B'][df['C']==0].to_dict() )
```

For example, let's suppose we have the following dataframe :

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
     {
         "A": [1, 1, 1, 1],
         "B": [0.2, 0.2, 0.02, 0.02],
         "C": [0.3, 0, 0.03, 0],
     }
 )

#    A     B     C
# 0  1  0.20  0.30
# 1  1  0.20  0.00
# 2  1  0.02  0.03
# 3  1  0.02  0.00
```

**Update**

```py
r = df['A'].update( df['B'][df['C']==0].to_dict() )

print(r)
```

```
      A     B     C
0  1.00  0.20  0.30
1  0.20  0.20  0.00
2  1.00  0.02  0.03
3  0.02  0.02  0.00
```